# Magento 2.4.2 composer install PHP extension errors

Tags: magento2, php, php-7, magento2.4.2, php-extension

I am trying to set up a local Magento 2.4.2 instance just to experiment and develop some work, but I keep hitting a problem with PHP extensions when I run `composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition`

```bash
Creating a "magento/project-community-edition" project at "./project-community-edition"
Installing magento/project-community-edition (2.4.2)
  - Installing magento/project-community-edition (2.4.2): Extracting archive
Created project in /home/rafael/Desktop/project-community-edition
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.2 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.2].
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.2 requires ext-curl * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's curl extension.
  Problem 2
    - magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[3.0.0, ..., 3.3.0] require ext-curl * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's curl extension.
    - Root composer.json requires magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework ^3.0 -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-functional-testing-framework[3.0.0, ..., 3.3.0].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ffi.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

I already tried to install the extensions with the following command:

```bash
sudo apt-get install php7.4-opcache php7.4-pdo php7.4-calendar php7.4-ctype php7.4-dom php7.4-exif php7.4-ffi php7.4-fileinfo php7.4-ftp php7.4-gettext php7.4-iconv php7.4-json php7.4-mbstring php7.4-phar php7.4-posix php7.4-readline php7.4-shmop php7.4-simplexml php7.4-sockets php7.4-sysvmsg php7.4-sysvsem php7.4-sysvshm php7.4-tokenizer php7.4-xmlreader php7.4-xmlwriter php7.4-xsl
```

PHP version:

```bash
PHP 7.4.3 (cli) (built: Oct  6 2020 15:47:56) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.3, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Mysql version:

```bash
mysql  Ver 8.0.23-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

Elasticsearch version:

```json
{
  "name" : "magecomp4",
  "cluster_name" : "magento-local-app-dummy",
  "cluster_uuid" : "keE77f1bQyudHuyvNVFWYQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.11.1",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "deb",
    "build_hash" : "ff17057114c2199c9c1bbecc727003a907c0db7a",
    "build_date" : "2021-02-15T13:44:09.394032Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.7.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error refers to **PHP's curl extension missing** and don't see it in your php modules install command. You can run `php -m` to double-check and confirm it's really missing.

If it's missing, you should install it:

```bash
sudo apt-get install php7.4-curl
```

However, I would suggest you read the [documentation about required PHP settings](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/php-settings.html) and make sure that you have everything in there.

---

***Sidenote:*** It just occurred to me *(maybe I am wrong)* that when you ran the command

```bash
sudo apt-get install php7.4-opcache php7.4-pdo php7.4-calendar php7.4-ctype php7.4-dom php7.4-exif php7.4-ffi php7.4-fileinfo php7.4-ftp php7.4-gettext php7.4-iconv php7.4-json php7.4-mbstring php7.4-phar php7.4-posix php7.4-readline php7.4-shmop php7.4-simplexml php7.4-sockets php7.4-sysvmsg php7.4-sysvsem php7.4-sysvshm php7.4-tokenizer php7.4-xmlreader php7.4-xmlwriter php7.4-xsl
```

it is possible that you thought that those extensions are missing since they were referred in the error message by the text *To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:'*. That message only tells you which additional .ini files were parsed as a hint where to look and not which extensions were missing.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I understood my mistake by looking at the message with more attention, thanks!

Comment: You are most welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone searching for php8.1 ヅ

```
sudo apt-get install php8.1-opcache php8.1-pdo php8.1-calendar php8.1-ctype php8.1-dom php8.1-exif php8.1-ffi php8.1-fileinfo php8.1-ftp php8.1-gettext php8.1-iconv php8.1-mbstring php8.1-phar php8.1-posix php8.1-readline php8.1-shmop php8.1-simplexml php8.1-sockets php8.1-sysvmsg php8.1-sysvsem php8.1-sysvshm php8.1-tokenizer php8.1-xmlreader php8.1-xmlwriter php8.1-xsl php8.1-soap php8.1-bcmath php8.1-intl php8.1-gd php8.1-mysql php8.1-zip
```